# proximity profile api for ios

Tags: ios, sensors, proximity

I want to generate alert sound, if iPhone goes beyond the specific distance from my BLE enabled Tag.
For that I need proximity sensor profile to implement.
I searched for Proximity sensor profile API for ios, but didn't get any successful result.

Comment: Have the same question, have you got any idea?